# Proving $X_t$ is a Martingale with respect to natural filtration

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, wiener-measure

So I have $W_t$ is a Wiener process where $X_t = W_t^2-t$. I need to prove $X_t$ is a martingale.

I know that in order to prove $X-t$ is a Martingale, we must have:

1) $\mathbb E[|X_t|]<∞$

2) $\mathbb E[X_t|F_s]=X_s $ for $0 ≤ s ≤ t$

I have started applying these properties to my question but none of the examples I have are similar to this one. So far I have:

$\mathbb E[|X_t|] = \mathbb E[|W_t^2 -t|]$ = $\int_∞^∞ w -t dw$ and $\int_∞^∞ -(w -t) dw$

I am not sure if these are correct, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is your problem only about 1)? Can you prove 2)?

Comment: About 1): Can you prove that $W^2_t \in L^1$?

Comment: @Tom Both 1) and 2) pose problems but it is mainly 1) I am struggling with. I can't prove that, can you clarify what $L^1$ is?

Comment: For (1), $\mathsf{E}|W_t^2-t|\le t\mathsf{E}W_1^2+t=2t$.